# Visual Basic on Excel: Iterate though a list of rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have a following code pattern. It's iterating through row 1, 3, and 25. There is no pattern. I was wondering if I can can condense such code where I can store these row numbers in a list and iterate a for loop based on that list. Note that for each row, only a range of columns is considered.

```
Dim rng As Range, cl As Range

Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A3:A10")

For Each cell In rng
    cell.NumberFormat = "ddMMMyyyy"
Next cell

Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("C3:C10")

For Each cell In rng
    cell.NumberFormat = "ddMMMyyyy"
Next cell

Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("Y3:Y10")

For Each cell In rng
    cell.NumberFormat = "ddMMMyyyy"
Next cell
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to loop. You can condense into a single line

```
Range("A3:A10,C3:C10,Y3:Y10").NumberFormat = "ddMMMyyyy"
```